# Should we add the [star-trek] tag to all of the Star Trek questions that don't have it?

Tags: status-completed, tags, retagging, discussion

I've just searched for questions tagged [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng) without being tagged [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek). There are 79 of them, right now. [(Here's where you can find them.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng%2B-star-trek)) There also [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos), [star-trek-voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyager), and [star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9) questions without [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek). Should we edit them? Do we actually need that tag on every single ST:TNG question?

Comment: My opinion is that yes, we should have it on those question.

Comment: If the consensus is with you, then there will be several hundred questions to be retagged, so we should probably organise another tag cleanup event.

Comment: I'm broadly in favour, as long as it's someone else doing the actual work of retagging. Since the numbers are into the hundreds,  I'd suggest we ask a programmer to do it rather that actually retagging each question individually.

Comment: @Richard If I do it myself, I'll probably get a silver badge plus a gold badge. It'll only take around an hour. I'll do it!

Comment: @Mithrandir  - I was more concerned about the fact that it would absolutely bury the front page

Comment: Related posts: [one](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1997/star-trek-franchise-tag-for-questions-that-relate-to-the-entire), [two](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4860/tag-hierarchies), [three](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/part-of-franchise-questions-tagged-with-franchise), [four](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/does-this-question-need-5-star-trek-tags). It seems the [tag:star-trek] tag was meant for questions about **all** ST and the more specific tags for more specific questions, but it hasn't quite worked out that way ...

Comment: This problem is more severe - [those are](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bstar-trek%5D) the question that mention Star Trek but aren't tagged appropriately. There are __590__ such questions; assuming 20% don't actually need it, we're still up to our antennae in retagging work.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Star+trek+-%5Bstar-trek*%5D+is%3Aq) is a search for those that mention Star Trek and have no sort of st tag on them.

Answer (score 13):

After some discussion I'm fine with retagging all star-trek questions with the generic franchise tag. However, I would like it to be a coordinated effort during off peak (ie weekend evening) hours.

It would appear that you have already started changing them, without much discussion or allowing this meta question to receive votes.

Comment: I did start; the meta question was actually mostly to put the idea of an organized effort out there.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no way to achieve this retagging automatically.**

- We could *synonymise* [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos), [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng), etc. with the master [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) tag, but this wouldn't add the master tag to the old questions with the more specific tags, and it would mean no new questions would be able to have the specific tags.
- Alternatively a moderator could *merge* the specific tags into the master tag, but that would mean losing the specific tags on all the old questions.

  Neither of these outcomes is desirable.

**The community appears to be against doing it manually.**

- As @JackBNimble suggested in his answer above, the manual retagging of all questions tagged [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng) etc. without being tagged [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) would be a massive undertaking which shouldn't be done bit by bit (messing up the front page for weeks or months) but in one coordinated effort.
- And the response to [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9207/when-should-we-do-another-tag-cleanup) was resoundingly against having another big manual tag cleanup effort any time soon. Most of those who responded or voted there felt that such a cleanup would cause more problems than it solved.

So it doesn't look as if this retagging is actually going to get done in the near future.

### But we can still search easily for Star Trek questions!

One of the main purposes of tags is to aid searchability, and one of the main reasons it's undesirable for not all Star Trek questions to be tagged [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) is that it makes it hard for people to easily find questions about Star Trek. But in fact **we can search for all Star Trek questions**, even with the tags in their current state!

Just type `[star-trek*]` into the search box, and you'll get to [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek+or+star-trek-tng+or+star-trek-ds9+or+star-trek-voyager+or+star-trek-tos+or+star-trek-data+or+star-trek-enterprise+or+star-trek-2009+or+star-trek-q+or+star-trek-eu+or+star-trek-into-darkness+or+star-trek-dominion+or+star-trek-beyond+or+star-trek-reboot+or+star-trek-uniforms+or+star-trek-emh+or+star-trek-first-contact+or+star-trek-motion-picture+or+star-trek-insignias+or+star-trek-generations), which lists every question with **every.damn.tag** that starts with the words "star-trek". The existence of this search ability eliminates a lot of the practical problems of not having a single unified Star Trek tag (even though I would still *like* very much to see every ST question tagged with [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)).

Comment: Funnily enough, that `[star-trek-*]` *excludes* questions tagged [star-trek] (and not one of the other tags in the list).

Comment: That's because one should use `[star-trek*]` (note there's no dash before the asterisk).

Comment: @SQB Thanks, fixed.

Comment: There's about 1 (one) negative answer on that cleanup post you mention and it has a score of -1 (minus one). Where's the "resounding againstness"? Or did you mean to link to some other question istead?

Comment: @Cahir Hmm, the score of that answer has changed quite a lot since last time I looked.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach This question/answer is old :P