# When should we do another tag cleanup?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Recently, I've been looking at tags, and realized that some things really need to be cleaned up. Like all those [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) questions [without the star-trek tag.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng+-star-trek) While we're at it, why not clean up other tags, too?

When should we organize another tag cleanup?

Comment: I think as the questions are already tagged [tag:star-trek-tng], do we need the [tag:star-trek] on them?  Sounds redundant to me :)

Comment: @Dawny33 See [this question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/should-we-add-the-star-trek-tag-to-all-of-the-star-trek-questions-that-dont-h).

Comment: First we need to pin down **exactly what retagging to do** in this tag cleanup event. Will it be *only* putting [tag:star-trek] on all Star Trek questions, or will there be more (e.g. getting rid of the [tag:real-world] tag)? *Then* we can decide when to do it.

Comment: I vote "never". What was the specific benefit from the last round? How did it benefit the site more than, for example, correcting bad spelling or improving question titles?

Comment: @Mike - I care. I just don't see the benefit. Also it mucks up the front page so I'm interested to know what metric you use to justify the damage caused.

Comment: What "damage" does bumping a post do? You mean 'noise' ? That noise is what keeps SE healthy.

Comment: @Valorum - Correcting bad spelling and improving question titles, for some of us, is our goal in life. What's the problem here?

Comment: When? Some time before [yesterday](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9850/how-many-tag-edits-should-we-allow-per-day?lq=1), apparently.

Answer (score -1):

Per my comment, I'm going to say "Never" or at the very least "Not for a long time".

For over a month now, the 'tagging team' have been pretty active in destroying lesser used tags, adding all manner of synonyms and untagging questions. What's been confusing me is *why?*

Whilst it's quite straightforward  to see the damage caused (repeatedly flooding the front page with dozens of minor edits) where I'm struggling is trying to see what the benefit actually is.

I'd like you to elect a spokesperson who can explain (using graphs and stats) how all this retagging has helped the site.

**Until then, I think you should stop.**