# Retagging some questions from [klingon] to [klingon-language] would be a most logical action

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

There's currently the tag [klingon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) and the tag [klingon-language](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language). As Klingon is probably the most famous fictional language around, it having a separate tag from Klingons in general is justified.

However, some questions currently in [klingon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) are solely about the language, and so should be retagged accordingly.

(For those wondering about the question title: see [Who owns Klingon? Lawsuit draws battle over invented languages into court](http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2016/apr/29/star-trek-fan-film-klingon-paramount-cbs-lawsuit?CMP=soc_568))

Comment: Klingons don't use logic! We shall destroy all tags!

Answer (score 4):

### Update: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There were eight questions tagged [klingon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) which didn't have the [klingon-language](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language) tag and should have had it, and I've now added it to all of these:

1. [Was Huttese based on Klingon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108748/was-huttese-based-on-klingon)
2. [Is there any more Klingon Opera?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103184/is-there-any-more-klingon-opera)
3. [Is there a Klingon word for kitten?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73957/is-there-a-klingon-word-for-kitten)
4. [Within-universe, is Klingon a constructed language?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59869/within-universe-is-klingon-a-constructed-language)
5. [Is the Klingon language the only constructed language seen on-screen?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29190/is-the-klingon-language-the-only-constructed-language-seen-on-screen)
6. [What is this Klingon Santa saying?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28205/what-is-this-klingon-santa-saying)
7. [Was Klingon used in any of the Star Wars movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24112/was-there-klingon-used-in-any-of-star-wars-movies)
8. [Is the Klingon language fully realized, or just a handful of disconnected phrases?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1228/is-the-klingon-language-fully-realized-or-just-a-handful-of-disconnected-phrase)

<strike>IMO, this is few enough to be able to retag them all in a day or two without awaking the [Wrath of Meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bglo6.png) and bringing the [Doom of Retaggers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9207/when-should-we-do-another-tag-cleanup) down upon your head. I'll be happy to help with this.</strike>

But **please don't do too many at once**: we don't want to flood the front page with old questions bumped by tag edits, especially relatively minor tag edits like this. A useful rule of thumb is to ensure that at most 5 of the top 15 questions on the front page of the site were last edited by you.

---

There were also two questions which did have the [klingon-language](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language) tag but were also tagged [klingon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) despite not being to do with Klingons or Klingon culture in general but just their language:

11. [Grammar and quality check for a Klingon warning notice for server room](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118448/grammar-and-quality-check-for-a-klingon-warning-notice-for-server-room)
12. [Klingon for 'arrow'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97330/klingon-for-arrow)

I just removed the [klingon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) tag from these two.

Comment: Per the [agreed guidelines on bulk-editing](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1743/massive-retagging-editing), retagging ten questions is a bit OTT, but not by much. Do it over the course of twelve hours and it wouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: @Richard Yep. I even said "in a day or two" so as to be on the safe side, especially since the site is quieter on weekends. Glad you agree :-)

Comment: Do you both feel better now that this has been done?