# The Big Edit Event (is finished)

Tags: discussion, retagging, editing, images

Now that we have a [broad consensus on having an edit event](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10678/is-it-time-to-organize-a-major-editing-event) to deal with the broken links caused by the [HTTPS update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only), we now need to coordinate the event itself.

**UPDATE #2**
The Big Event is now (largely) finished). If you want to do any more editing, please refer to the earlier guidelines on mass-edits. No more than 5-10 a day, max, please.

<s>**UPDATE**

It looks like we've been able to edit all (or at least almost all) of the broken image links in double-quick time.</s>

If you still want to help out, others are working on the Star Trek and LOTR tags (see below).

### What are our goals and what can I do to help?

The goal is to replace all broken HTTPS links in the shortest time possible, to minimise disruption. There's a [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur) query here that will help you to locate the broken links (Don't start from the *top downwards* unless you want to find a lot of duplicated effort!)

### When?

Since the links are broken now, I propose we start **immediately**, with a goal of completing the task within the **next 48-72 hours**

### Anything else?

Several users felt that it would be a good idea to tag on (pun intended) a retagging event aimed at sorting out our LOTR and Star Trek tags. Assuming they've got a consensus on those we should consider those a *secondary objective.*

---

[image]

Comment: Does this mean we start __now__ or after we have consensus here? :D I'm confused... cc @Randal'Thor

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Ladies and Gentlemen. **Start your editing!!!**

Comment: @Gallifreyan We already have consensus on the other post to have a Big Edit Event at *some* point. The only issue remaining is exactly when to do it, and this weekend seems as good a time as any.

Comment: My Copy Editor badge will shine from here to Gallifrey!

Comment: By the way, that SE query has some deprecated data, due to Community batch-editing editable http links yesterday

Comment: @Gallifreyan Nothing we can do about that until Data.SE is updated in about 12 hours' time.

Comment: @Randal'Thor can the query be edited to show when the post was last edited? That'd save time, because I just opened 4 no-longer-http posts in a row.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Probably (you'd need to ask someone with more SEDE-fu than I), but in any case edits made in the last week **won't show up** on Data.SE at all until the weekly update in 12 hours' time.

Comment: Let's get to it!!! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_hNk5QclHE

Comment: I've added a Community Event to the sidebar for this.

Comment: You know, I think we caught all dead images! (At least the query doesn't show a post I haven't visited. Hurray, just under 4 hours! Now the tags...

Comment: So this is why it looks like this site is entirely about Tolkien right now...

Comment: @zenzelezz - And Star Trek. Personally I could give a crap about the tag editing but it seems to make them happy.

Comment: Could you add [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10696/how-should-we-tag-marvel-and-dc-as-a-whole-considering-how-weve-done-so) to the head? About editing DC and Marvel tags.

Comment: I would also say some `story-identification` need to be changed to `episode-identification`, but it is such a drag.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - We don't have a consensus on editing those en-masse

Comment: @Randal'thor - Can you give Napoleon a prod. He was keen to fix the batman tags. He might as well do it now.

Comment: I see. There's an [older thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1521/702360), but it doesn't have many upvotes either.

Comment: Um ... I hate to say it, but there's [another 69 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.scifi/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2011-01-11&EndDate=2017-03-11) we missed when checking for broken images. Do we want to mess up the *meta* front page as well? (Admittedly a large proportion of those 69 are on the same two threads, which reduces the amount of messing up. But pushing new meta posts off the front page is worse than pushing new main-site posts off, because it could mean some policy discussions never get the eyeballs they need.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm tempted to say "leave 'em". The majority are decidedly aged and I see no benefit in updating the old moderator election threads.

Comment: @Randal'Thor agree with Valorum, and what you posted in chat.

Comment: "*No more than 5-10 a day, max, please.*" - I thought the usual guideline was more along the lines of "no more than 5 among the top 15 on the front page"?

Answer (score 13):

### Acknowledgements

Let's have a big round of applause for all those who [helped take part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge5Do.png) in the Big Edit Event (that image shows the number of edits made from Saturday/Sunday midnight up to now; I believe Valorum was the only person who took part on Saturday but less on Sunday):

[image: CreationEdge]
[image: Mithrandir]
[image: Edlothiad]
[image: Gallifreyan]
[image: tobiasvl]
[image: Bellerophon]
[image: Valorum]

Special thanks to **CreationEdge**, who not only did nearly 2000 manual edits all by himself but also took personal charge of the Marvel/DC stage of the operation. Without him, we could never have done anywhere near as much as we did in this event. We salute you, Captain Edge.

### Parts of the project

- **Fixing broken images.** This is the most important. [This Data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur) (set the date range to run from 2011-01-11 to 2017-03-11) provided a full list of ~200 posts with images that need fixing.
- **Star Trek tags.** There's a consensus [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9184/31394) to tag all questions about Star Trek with the generic [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) tag. There were several hundred of these, all now retagged.
- **Tolkien tags.** There's a consensus [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10655/31394) to keep [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) for questions about the region, [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) for questions about the author himself, and a new [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) tag for questions about his works. This took a *lot* of retagging, over 1000 questions - details below.
- **DC/Marvel tags.** See [CreationEdge's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10698/31394) for details.

---

### Organisation of Tolkien edits

**1. [tolkien]**

I had a look through the 905 (!) questions tagged [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien). Most of them weren't about the author but only about some of his works, so I retagged the 71 that were (at least arguably) specifically author-relevant with [j-r-r-tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-r-r-tolkien) and then mod-merged the [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) tag into [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium). (*Not that it really matters whether or not we include the initials in the tag name, but we do already have a distinct [christopher-tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christopher-tolkien) tag, and renaming [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) to [j-r-r-tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-r-r-tolkien) made the merging step easier. I can always mod-rename it back to [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) if anyone objects.*)

**2. [middle-earth]**

This was a similar job to [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien), but on a smaller scale (only about 300 questions to [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien)'s 900). I merged this tag with [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium), thus retagging most of those 300 questions in one fell swoop. The rest - the list I made before the merge, which can be found in the [revision history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/10693/10) of this post - had [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) re-added to them by hand. (I was quite liberal with allowing the tag to be kept; it's quite possible that some of these questions don't really deserve it.)

**3. Everything else**

There were also 1000+ questions with other Tolkien-related tags (specifically [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings), [the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit), or [silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/silmarillion)) but NOT tagged [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) or [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth). Since the individual work tags should of course be kept, adding [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) to all these questions had to be done by hand rather than with mod-merges. Thanks to a great deal of effort by many worthy community members, we completed this operation earlier today.

At this point:

- All [j-r-r-tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-r-r-tolkien) and [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth) questions are sensibly tagged. Don't worry about them.
- All [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) questions should have that tag (I can't guarantee that the *other* tags on all such questions are necessarily appropriate), and - hopefully - all that should have it do.
- [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) is dead, gone, and buried. (With apologies to [@JasonBaker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/231/tolkien), but he'll automatically get a gold tag badge in [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) to replace the one he's lost in [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien).)

Comment: What if there are dead links, where images no longer exist? I'll just delete them, since there is no way to recover the image.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Keep a list of those posts, e.g. in an answer to this question. We may be able to recover some of the images, using the Wayback Machine or other tricks. (I managed this with some broken images over on Puzzling just today.)

Comment: Weird - http images from Stack Imgur are displayed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68843/graphic-novel-where-protagonist-is-an-architect-that-doesnt-need-sleep/68850#68850)

Comment: Ah, OK. Let me eat something and I'll get started.

Comment: Will get started as soon as I'm back to my computer!

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgment! Special thanks to __Valorum__ and __Creation Edge__ for fixing missing and broken images!

Answer (score 6):

My thanks go to **Valorum** and **Creation Edge** for fixing missing and broken images!

---

**Posts with dead images - please notify the author of the post and add the links here.**

Links to those images were dead - I could not retrieve them.

- [Which 2015 technologies were correctly predicted by Back to the Future II?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95971/which-2015-technologies-were-correctly-predicted-by-back-to-the-future-ii/95972#95972)
- <s>[Who is the huge soldier among Zod's retinue in Man of Steel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68872/who-is-the-huge-soldier-among-zods-retinue-in-man-of-steel)</s>
- <s>[Help with A Diagram of the Races & Mythology of The Lord of the Rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26890/help-with-a-diagram-of-the-races-mythology-of-the-lord-of-the-rings)</s>
- <s>[Why did Sméagol turn into a 'creature' when addicted to the ring, but not Bilbo Baggins?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47868/why-did-sm%C3%A9agol-turn-into-a-creature-when-addicted-to-the-ring-but-not-bilbo/47869#47869)</s>
- <s>[Which Myers-Briggs personality is Hermione?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/which-myers-briggs-personality-is-hermione/9200#9200)</s>
- <s>[Identify source of picture (probably "Doom" related)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/identify-source-of-picture-probably-doom-related/34267#34267)</s>
- [Rise of the Planet of the Apes - Used software?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6347/rise-of-the-planet-of-the-apes-used-software/6348#6348)
- <s>[In what show did a man travel back in time whenever he heard ‘Do It Again’ by The Kinks?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52400/in-what-show-did-a-man-travel-back-in-time-whenever-he-heard-do-it-again-by-th/52402#52402)</s>
- <s>[What powers Wonder Woman's invisible plane?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52390/what-powers-wonder-womans-invisible-plane/52392#52392)</s>
- <s>[What's the origin of "One does not simply Telnet into Mordor"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10952/whats-the-origin-of-one-does-not-simply-telnet-into-mordor/10972#10972)</s>
- <s>[Can't you just bite off a face hugger?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8856/cant-you-just-bite-off-a-face-hugger)</s>
- <s>[What is the largest ship in the Star Trek Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54551/what-is-the-largest-ship-in-the-star-trek-universe/54552#54552)</s>
- <s>[Are the Nausicaans and the Kradin related?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104648/are-the-nausicaans-and-the-kradin-related)</s>
- <s>[Any ideas what these Dr Who monsters are?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54562/any-ideas-what-these-dr-who-monsters-are/54569#54569)</s>
- [A 80's comic could be late 70's book I read as a kid](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26926/a-80s-comic-could-be-late-70s-book-i-read-as-a-kid) (Subbed a best-guess pic)
- <s>[Heinlein -- long hair in 1958?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50676/heinlein-long-hair-in-1958/50684#50684) (Subbed a best-guess pic)</s>
- <s>[What powers Wonder Woman's invisible plane?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52390/what-powers-wonder-womans-invisible-plane/52392#52392)</s>
- <s>[How did the cookfire get hot enough to melt gold in Game of Thrones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/how-did-the-cookfire-get-hot-enough-to-melt-gold-in-game-of-thrones/60617#60617)</s>
- [Which buildings were used to create Hogwarts in the Harry Potter films?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79184/which-buildings-were-used-to-create-hogwarts-in-the-harry-potter-films/79187#79187)

Comment: Using the Wayback Machine can work. When I get on my computer, I can see what I can do.

Answer (score 5):

[Here's some of the DC tag cleanup that's ongoing](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10697/31178)

Ignore the dc-comics bit in the URLs. The two tags were always synonyms and a long standing meta meant to swap them. During the event the swap happened and now [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc) is the parent tag.

(Marvel is upcoming, one thing at a time):

Whichever tag is missing in the search is the one that needs to be added.

<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/man-of-steel+-dc-extended-universe</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-v-superman+-dc-extended-universe</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/man-of-steel+-dc-comics</s>  
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-v-superman+-dc-comics</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/man-of-steel+-superman

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-v-superman+-superman</s> <-- **Deciding that since BvS is technically split between two "franchises" but really just the DCEU" it only needs to have the DCEU tag**
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-flash-2014+-arrowverse</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-flash-2014+-dc-comics</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrow+-arrowverse</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrow+-dc-comics</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supergirl+-dc-comics</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supergirl-2015+-arrowverse</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supergirl-2015+-dc-comics</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman+-dc-comics</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice-league-unlimited+-dcau</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suicide-squad-2016+-dc-extended-universe</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suicide-squad-2016+-dc-comics</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suicide-squad+-dc-comics</s>

<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dcau+-dc-comics</s>
<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe+-dc-comics</s>

<s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beast-boy+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batgirl+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquaman+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nightwing+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mr-freeze+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-lantern+-dc-comics 
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greent-lantern-tas+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doomsday+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-new-52+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-arrow+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robin+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/krypton+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kryptonite+-dc-comics

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wonder-woman+-dc-comics</s>

There's probably more DC to be done, in bits and pieces, but I think these are the major offenders. Marvel is incoming, and it's gonna be a HULKing BEAST of a job.

Comment: All right, all the ones currently in the list are done, except the BvS one.

Comment: I feel like the BvS one... Since it's part of 2 franchises, it's better off just using the DCEU tag only, and not either Batman or Superman as a rule, so I'm good with calling it done.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the start of the [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) list. Do these by group order, because it'll eliminate having to retag the same question.

Ignore the marvel-comics bit in the URLs. The two tags were always synonyms and a long standing meta meant to swap them. During the event the swap happened and now [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) is the parent tag.

<s>**1.** All of these need to [captain-america](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america) + [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) + [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe). Use best judgment if some don't actually need any.</s>

- <s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-civil-war+-captain-america</s>
- <s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-tws+-captain-america</s>
- <s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-tfa+-captain-america</s>

**2a**. All of these need [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) + [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe):

- <s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-civil-war+-marvel-cinematic-universe</s>
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-tws+-marvel-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america-tfa+-marvel-cinematic-universe
- <s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor-the-dark-world+-marvel-cinematic-universe</s>
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy+-marvel-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2+-marvel-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daredevil-2015+-marvel-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luke-cage+-marvel-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agent-carter+-marvel-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man-2+-marvel-cinematic-universe <-- And [iron-man](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man-3+-marvel-cinematic-universe  <-- And [iron-man](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-strange-2016+-marvel-cinematic-universe <-- and [doctor-strange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-strange)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-ultron+-marvel-cinematic-universe <-- And [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agents-of-shield+-marvel-cinematic-universe

**2b.** All of these need [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) + [x-men-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-cinematic-universe)

- <s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-days-of-future-past+-x-men-cinematic-universe</s>
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-apocalypse+-x-men-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-origins-wolverine+-x-men-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-2000+-x-men-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-2+-x-men-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-first-class+-x-men-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-last-stand+-x-men-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logan+-x-men-cinematic-universe
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-wolverine+-x-men-cinematic-universe

**3.** All of these need [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics).

- <s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-man-tas+-marvel</s>
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-man-2+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-amazing-spider-man-2+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-amazing-spider-man+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider-man+-marvel
- <s>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-incredible-hulk+-marvel</s>
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ant-man+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-man+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adamantium+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-cinematic-universe+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-america+-marvel
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe+-marvel

And there was a bunch more that's was too much work to list out here as it was getting done. Basically, all those pesky movies and TV shows that had the same names as the characters now *don't*. And there's a bunch of other characters that I caught and just fixed as I found them without generating a URL to link here.

Answer (score 2):

### [Small (27 questions) *The Expanse* re-tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10665/tags-for-the-expanse-book-series-and-tv-series)

There seem to be more questions related to the TV show than the novels. So, per [CreationEdge's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10667/23384), should a mod rename [the-expanse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse) to [the-expanse-2015](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse-2015)? If so I can re-tag the questions about the novels with [the-expanse-novels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse-novels).

Also: Should these novel-specific tags be deleted/added as synonyms?

- [leviathan-wakes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leviathan-wakes)
- [calibans-war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calibans-war)

Comment: Per CreationEdge's answer all individual works get tags, so last part is no-no

Comment: @Gallifreyan I still don't understand that part. CreationEdge also said "So, there's not a need to tag Caliban's War individually, which Gallifreyan's answer also addresses."

Comment: @Gallifreyan But I don't really care either way. Should tags be created for the other books in the series then?

Comment: I've created [tag:the-expanse-novels] and retagged the relevant questions. A mod can probably rename [tag:the-expanse] to [tag:the-expanse-2015] now.

Comment: @tobiasvl [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: @Randal'Thor Danke. Feel free to add [tag:status-completed] to my original question: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10665/tags-for-the-expanse-book-series-and-tv-series

Comment: @Gallifreyan We have a minor exception for stuff like closed trilogy and series, but it's not being universally applied now so I'd just as soon leave the individual tags unless it's a problem and let Tolkien and Potter people keep that management to themselves.