# Should we use [dc], [vertigo-comics], or both, for questions about comics published by Vertigo?

Tags: discussion, tags

After I've read *The Sandman* I've started looking here for relevant questions to answer, and asking some of my own.

I noticed that the tagging for them is inconsistent and debatable. Some didn't have any publisher tags, some had [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics), some had [vertigo-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertigo-comics).

Now, Vertigo is an imprint of DC, created to publish more adult-oriented material. Here's the catch: Vertigo was founded in 1993, so most of the cool stuff - *The Sandman*, *V for Vendetta*, *Watchmen*, *Hellblazer*, *Swamp Thing*, and others - has started in 1980s and was initially published by DC, and then moved to the Vertigo imprint.

I don't think it is correct to collect all of those works under the same [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc) tag. Vertigo has been separated from DC for a reason - their comics are thematically different, geared towards a more adult audience. There is also the problem of overlapping of universes: Vertigo characters (apart from Constantine and Swamp Thing) rarely make appearances in the DC universe, and vice versa.

Questions to consider:

1. How should we tag questions about comics?
2. how should we tag questions about films based on comics?

How should we proceed? Completely separate Vertigo and DC? Use them in tandem?

---

To provide some context, there appear to be 32 questions tagged with [watchmen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen) and 3 questions tagged with [watchmen-2009](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen-2009); 6 questions tagged with [hellblazer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hellblazer); 4 questions about [v-for-vendetta](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/v-for-vendetta); and whooping 37 questions about my dear [sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sandman).

Why am I listing this? just to point that any potential retag will be relatively easy compared to [what we've done](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10691/70236). I'm not saying we should schedule another mass edit event - I can take the responsibility for retags, doing 3 or 4 a day, no rush.

I'm not asking for immediate retagging action, I just want to have a policy on hands.

Comment: Also, can we rename [vertigo-comics] to [vertigo], similar to what has been done to Marvel and DC?

Comment: My only worry about this is that we've had Constantine crossovers with Arrowverse. So are we looking at `dc` `vertigo` `arrow` `arrowverse` `constantine` just for questions about those crossovers? If so, we're already at max tags.

Comment: @CreationEdge since it's Arrow, I don't think we need Vertigo there. Same goes for Constantine's appearances in JL.

Comment: @CreationEdge I also wouldn't think you'd need _both_ [tag:dc] and [tag:vertigo], since Vertigo is a DC imprint?

Comment: Yeah, I feel like in this case you'd not need dc, anymore than we tag disney on marvel questions

Comment: Ooorrrr... To avoid the confusion... Head to [literature.se]! ;)

Comment: @Gallifreyan no there is famous film called Vertigo, so it's better to keep it as Vertigo comics.

Comment: @covfefe Is there a chance we'll need a tag for this film, since it's not sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: @Gallifreyan I don't see it as SFF film but just for the sake of name popularity and I am not even sure about SFFness of the film as I have not seen it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say use the tag that is relevant to the question.

Example: In one of first books of "Sandman" we have crossover with "Hellblazer" and "JLA". So if you'd ask something like "Have Endless appeared anywhere again in other comic book series" you could use all three tags [vertigo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertigo), [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc), [sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sandman). If you'd ask only for something related to the "Sandman" series itself, I'd drop the [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc).

When it comes to comic-based movies, separate tag should be used only if the movie adaptation varies SIGNIFICANTLY to the original (i.e. non existing yet [lucifer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer) and [lucifer-tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer-tv-series) )

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Answer (score -3):

### Both

As Vertigo is property of DC, a guy following DC can find dedicated Vertigo questions useful. This is actually a scenario when hierarchical tag structure can be useful, but otherwise we can make use of both tags.

What can be thumbs down point against using both tags anyway...

Comment: "A guy following DC can find dedicated Vertigo questions useful" - then follow `vertigo` as well! I name multiple tags that would be interesting to people, but that doesn't mean they should be applied together. As the OP says, Vertigo and DC are different in terms of themes and stories, except for an occasional overlap, in which case _we will_ apply both tags.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Maybe, he never encountered the Vertigo tag on the site at all, but if the question has DC tag, he can get the question in the email inbox or feed reader.

Comment: I disagree. The purpose of tags is not to recommend related works or universes. A DC reader who is not aware of, or interested in Vertigo will most likely not benefit from this, as _the two publishers are different_. That said, since both questions will have the `comics` tag, chances are they will already appear in the "related questions" tab.