# Motion to re-define the [lucifer] and [sandman] tags!

Tags: discussion, tags

Browsing through [lucifer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer) questions, I noticed two things:

1. Majority is about the character who debuted in *The Sandman*, or Mike Carey's *Lucifer* series.
2. That's not what the tag guidance says. To quote,

   > Lucifer was a fallen angel in Christian mythology and commonly associated as Satan. The name Lucifer is used in several works for characters that are powerful and evil, usually with some kind of fall from grace in their background. Of note is the DC Comics character from Sandman, whose depiction draws heavily from Milton's Paradise Lost.

It appears that the tag was intended to be about all portrayals of Lucifer in all works; but it happened that the most popular one seemed to be the Vertigo character.

Same goes for [sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sandman). Usage guidance:

> The Sandman is a folklore character who brings sleep and dreams. He is in particular the titular character of a series of comic books by Neil Gaiman, where he is also known as Dream or Morpheus.

And wiki:

> The Sandman is a figure of European folklore, who brings good dreams by sprinkling sand onto the eyes of children. This tag applies to any incarnation of the folklore figure.
>
> An important incarnation is the titular character (also known as Dream or Morpheus) of neil-gaiman's series of graphic novels The Sandman.

---

Effectively, those two tags are now *character*, rather than *franchise*, or series tags. [We don't want character tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6840/70236) to breed. [We don't always adhere](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=36815898#36815898) to that policy, but I think it's a good one in this case:

- So far it seems that questions about those characters have been limited to their portrayals in Vertigo comics, with no exceptions for Sandman, and 3 exceptions for Lucifer ([Supernatural](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134245/why-didnt-lucifer-bring-back-ruby), [closed as too broad](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128553/effect-of-angels-amputating-wings), [story identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108349/name-of-story-about-jehovah-and-satan-making-stable-reality-out-of-chaos)).

Re-defining those tags to be specifically about the respective Vertigo series would prevent possible confusions, and bring those tags closer to our established policy (i.e. no character tags for less popular characters), the purpose of the tagging system (tags should aid search process; tags should reflect what the question is *about*, not what it mentions).

For [sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sandman), I propose we rename it to [the-sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sandman), specify in the guidance that it is about the Vertigo comic series (and maybe say that it should be used with [vertigo-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertigo-comics), if [this proposal](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10800/70236) gets enough votes. E.g.

> To be used for the dark fantasy comic series written by Neil Gaiman, as well as its spin-offs. Use with [comics] and [vertigo-comics] tags.

<sub>I could then write a nice wiki for the tag, with fancy pictures and quotes</sub>

For [lucifer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer), I propose we state clearly that it is for the Vertigo series written by Mike Carey, and the new 2016 *Lucifer* series.

The total number of retags then amounts to 3: simply purge it from [those](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134245/why-didnt-lucifer-bring-back-ruby) [three](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128553/effect-of-angels-amputating-wings) [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108349/name-of-story-about-jehovah-and-satan-making-stable-reality-out-of-chaos). Supernatural's Lucifer can live without own tag; Biblical Lucifer... well, we don't have enough questions about that for him to have a say in this.

Comment: I wrote the [lucifer] tag wiki excerpt to be about the Sandman character. The edit reviewer changed it entirely: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/128572/revisions

Comment: @amaranth I see. _Maybe I should've just gone and edit those myself :)_

Comment: How about Marvel's Sandman?

Comment: @SQB No questions - no tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[lucifer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer) should be restored to [amaranth/Molag Bal's original wiki excerpt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/128572/revisions)

> For questions about the DC Comics character Lucifer, the comic book series about him, and the TV series which is based on the comic book series. The character first appeared in The Sandman and then in his own comic book series; both series were published under the Vertigo imprint of DC Comics. The TV series premiered on Fox in 2016.

With a little tweak to specify it's about the Lucifer franchise, too.

Our current arrangement for character tags as such is that the first/most popular version of the character (as measured by our use on SFF, not anywhere else) gets the plain tag. If *other* versions exist, or there's room for confusion, we use prefixes and suffixes to clear things up.

Specific examples:

- [thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor) is separate from [thor-mythology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor-mythology) and [thor-stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thor-stargate)

  - See the description:

    > For questions about the Marvel character Thor and the related franchise. For other usages, use specific tags such as thor-mythology or thor-stargate.
- [star-trek-data](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-data) to clarify it's Data we're talking about, as `data` alone is too unclear
- [loki](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loki) and [odin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odin) are both the Marvel characters

If a Lucifer tag was ever needed for Christian depiction, we should use [lucifer-religion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer-religion) or something similar.

Similar guidance goes for [sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sandman).

There's no reason either [lucifer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer) or [sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sandman) *can't* be franchise tags, as both are franchises. They're, IMO, much less character tags, especially now that *Lucifer* is a TV show (and should get its own [lucifer-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer-2016) tag where necessary)

Comment: So... do we use them for the series or for the characters? I'm confused.

Comment: @Gallifreyan There ya go.

Comment: Also, renaming to `the-sandman` makes perfect sense to me, but it's sort of a separate issue so I don't want to tie it up into the usage patterns we have.

Comment: I think we could chunk `the-sandman` here as well. Since both don't make many appearances outside of their respective series, a question about character would also need to be about the series. The opposite doesn't apply, but the good thing is - it doesn't have to.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I included `sandman` here, just not specifically the renaming of the tag portion. Because we could rename, or make a synonym, and discussing that is best left for another answer.

Comment: It's just 40 questions, no one cares but a handful of folks, and most of them haven't been here for a while. It's all up to us :)

Comment: Is this our current arrangement though? I thought we didn't get any character tags at all.

Comment: @Gallifreyan We get character tags. `albus-dumbledore`, `star-trek-data`,`gandalf`, etc. They generally need better justification, but in the case of `sandman` and `lucifer` they're not _just_ character tags, they are complete franchises (whereas the other 3 I just listed are purely characters)

Answer (score 1):

I propose the use [the-sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sandman) for Neil Gaiman's series, keeping [sandman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sandman) for other uses — either the Marvel villain or the mythological character.

I propose to use [lucifer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer) for the spin-off.

Comment: That was the plan - I was just waiting for this to get enough upvotes for me to ping a mod to rename the tag.