# What is this no-change edit? How did it happen?

Tags: bug, editing

[One of my posts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86769) was apparently edited, but looking at the history, I see no visible changes. What happened here? (This question is motivated mainly by curiosity, but there must be some sort of bug in play.)

#### Inline view of edit history

[image: Edit history: inline view]

#### Side-by-side view of edit history

[image: Edit history: side by side]

#### Side-by-side Markdown view of edit history

[image: Edit history: side by side Markdown]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The edit description says "edited tags". I'd assume that the editor added/removed a tag which no longer exists and therefore doesn't show up in the edit history.

A little sleuthing confirmed my guess. Using the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20150909202533/https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86769/did-elrond-half-elven-have-any-title), we can see that in its original post-edit state, your question had the tags [tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien) and [middle-earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-earth), both of which were merged into the new franchise tag [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) during the [Big Edit Event](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10693/31394) before being separated out again. Presumably you'd originally posted it with just one of these tags and the editor added the other one. But the tag merge mapped both tags to [tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium) everywhere in the database, including in revision histories, so this became a null change.

Comment: That's cool. The "added two characters" is also explicable: (s)he added two characters by mistake, and then reverted that change within the edit grace period, but didn't change the automatic comment.